Thread safe token bucket algorithm
I have below code
public class TokenBucketRateLimiter implements RateLimiter {
    // Maximum number of tokens that can be accumulated in the bucket.
    private final long threshold;
    // Time unit for the token refill (in milliseconds).
    private final long windowUnit = 1000;
    // Current number of available tokens.
    private final AtomicLong tokens = new AtomicLong(0);
    // Timestamp of the last refill operation.
    private volatile long lastRefillTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

    /**
     * Constructs a TokenBucketRateLimiter with the specified threshold.
     *
     * @param threshold the maximum number of tokens that can be accumulated.
     */
    public TokenBucketRateLimiter(long threshold) {
        this.threshold = threshold;
        // Initialize the bucket to full capacity.
        this.tokens.set(threshold);
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to acquire a token from the bucket.
     *
     * @return true if a token was successfully acquired; false otherwise.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean tryAcquire() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // Calculate the number of tokens to add based on elapsed time since the last refill.
        long tokensToAdd = ((currentTime - lastRefillTimestamp) / windowUnit) * threshold;

        // Refill the bucket with the calculated number of tokens.
        if (tokensToAdd > 0) {
            // Ensure the bucket does not exceed its capacity.
            tokens.set(Math.min(threshold, tokens.addAndGet(tokensToAdd)));
            // Update the refill timestamp.
            lastRefillTimestamp = currentTime;
        }

        // Attempt to acquire a token.
        if (tokens.get() > 0) {
            // Decrement the token count and grant access.
            tokens.decrementAndGet();
            return true;
        }

        // Token bucket is empty; deny access.
        return false;
    }
}

This is simple one node token bucket implementation. Isn't it true that in the below code when I check
        // Attempt to acquire a token.
        if (tokens.get() > 0) {
            // Decrement the token count and grant access.
            tokens.decrementAndGet();
            return true;
        }


If the number of tokens was 1, tokens.get() will return 1. Two threads can still pass this check and can decrement it one after the other making tokens negative and allowing the second call to go through though it should not be allowed?
Is using synchronized the only way here? Or say Reentrant lock api?

Please specify your question and provide a more focused code example.

The javadoc for AtomicLong methods shows various calls for updating the state of token without locks or synchronization.

@curiousengineer DuncG was 100% right.  Yes, there's a race condition, but the Javadoc for AtomicLong shows you how to deal with it correctly (not how you're doing it now).

You are correct that there's danger of a race condition, and that synchronized or ReentrantLock could fix it.  However, you could instead do something like
long prevTokens = tokens.getAndUpdate(t -> Math.max(t-1, 0));
if (prevTokens > 0) { return true; }


Thanks, one follow up, I am wondering if this will at all then require synchronized. And if not, can it sometimes falsely say the api needs to be throttled? Just thinking aloud. I think this might work, and I can replace -1 with the tokens I need to grab if it is more than one I think?

Also, that is t in your lambda implementation? Won't that have a race condition?

No, it doesn't require synchronized.  No, it can't be wrong.  No, it won't have a race condition.  If you need more than one, you need to be cleverer about the lambda body, but the same general idea works.

In the code snippet I have, what is the value of t here? Can you please tell me that? Then I can try to connect the dots. thanks. Because I think t is the current token value taht is read and when other thread reads it, by then it will have changed already in some cases. Isn't it?

t is the current value, but getAndUpdate guarantees that it works atomically, that other threads cannot do anything that conflicts.  Please read the documentation.

I am a bit lost honestly. You have really tried helping, if you don't mind will you share the full final snippet of sample code looks like that I can glean carefully at to ensure there is no race condition?

I don't think that's going to help you.  You need to understand that getAndUpdate, along with other methods on AtomicLong, are guaranteed not to race, period.  You can't do set with addAndGet either, but getAndUpdate allows you to specify a function that is always atomically applied without risking races.

I understand it now. It is stating that if value becomes negative, set it to zero, else reduce by one. Also return the value before decrementing. And since this is atomic instruction, I also know that it will not let other thread mutate it until the current atomic one is done. Hence if 2 threads read non zero and each decrement by 1, it means value was at least 2 to begin with. I was just thinking on the wrong track. Yes this snippet can fix the issue in the original code

You right about this code being unsafe.
Correct version is:
    long old = tokens.get();
    while (old > 0) {
        if (tokens.compareAndSet(old, old - 1)) {
            return true;
        }
        old = tokens.get();
    }


Thanks, there is a minor flaw. The compareAndSet will fail if the old is modified. And let us say even after being modified, it was greater than Zero, we will still throttle the call. One solution would be to introduce retry, but then that can in theory cause a problem

I edited my answer. I forgot to update old after failed attempt to swap.

Thank you and this is where the theoretical notion of infinite loop comes. I think the way to get around it is, exponential backoff and do a retry and abort after some attempts. Correct? Secondly, is there any API in Java doc that can take care of all of this as others are hammering me with that suggestion in here? I doubt

No.  This does not risk an infinite loop and does not require backing off.  (If N threads are contending, there can only be N failures.)  This is a standard idiom.  There is no API built into Java that can do this for you, though some third-party libraries for rate limiters exist.

This can certainly cause it theoretically because I think in real life if the API requests keep coming then one thread can always get old greater than zero, then all incoming request can change the read value of old and compareAndSet condition will be false, and loop will keep repeating. This is very well possible.

@curiousengineer when more than one thread make an attempt at the same time, at least one of them will make progress. For all practical purposes, where the threads are doing more than executing these seven lines of code, there is enough chance for each thread to eventually proceed. Unless you have so many threads that some of them never get the CPU anyway. But that’s a problem on its own, not a problem of this piece of code.

@Holger you assessment may sound correct practically. There is literally a synchronization problems if this code is deployed in production and calls keep coming back to back. One or more threads can get stuck in an infinite while loop.
If you extend this, the number of stuck. threads will increase with time, and you will have no more threads left to honor any calls. If you are saying this is impossible, I do not think there is much to discuss with you on this then

@curiousengineer in your scenario when no threads left one of them have to succeed. Indeed there is a problem with high numbers of updates. One thread can stuck in quasi infinite loop. AtomicX are bad for high contention situation.

Let me restate here that this is an api throttler where api requests can keep coming one after the other forever and the token value also gets replenished, if you see the part of original code. Hence the solution suggested here, is prone to infinite loop and can actually put multiple threads over time in an infinite loop

@curiousengineer I agree with you. In some situation thread can stuck with updating value infinitely. In such situation one should use other ways of synchronization/ It doesn't mean this code is wrong. It means that you need to analyze usage of such code.

@curiousengineer all atomic operations work that way. Even those provided by the CPU itself work by trying and re-attempting when contented. It's all a matter of likelihood given by the ratio of time between attempts and the time needed for an attempt. Not even synchronized provides fairness and also ReentrantLock does not by default, which means they all bear the possibility that one thread gets stuck and the other gets the lock again and again when acquiring in short intervals. If fairness is a concern, ReentrantLock constructed as fair will do.
